# Angularjs: Use linky and ng-bind-html together in angular template

Tags: angularjs

I have this directive to compile:

```
var app = angular.module('mobApp.services');
app.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
                return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
            },
            function(value) {                
                element.html(value);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        );
    };
}])
```

I am using it here in my template:

```
<p compile="post.details | linky:'_blank'"></p>
```

If the data has any link its rendering well but its not rendering text like `<b>` as `&lt;b&gt;`. I just want the `<b>` as `<b>` without making the inside text bold.

If i use `ng-html-bind` all work fine but link doesn't work. If i use `linky` link work fine but rendering does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try with below changes?

```
var app = angular.module('mobApp.services');
app.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.compile, function(html) {
            element.html(html);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        });
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You may write a custom filter in which first use linky filter and put the tags back in there

```js
module.filter('linkyWithHtml', function($filter) {
  return function(value) {
    var linked = $filter('linky')(value);
    var replaced = linked.replace(/\&gt;/g, '>').replace(/\&lt;/g, '<');
    return replaced;
  };
});
```